# Change Grails GORM format without dropping existing tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have one Grails application that has been running for a while. But now I want to change the GORM format and I wonder if there are simple ways to do so, i.e. ways that I don't need to drop existing tables, only modifying my application will do.

To be specific, I used to have one HashSet field that is mapped to varbinary in DB. There are some existing rows in this User table.

```
public class User{
    //irrelevant attributes omitted
    HashSet<String> friends=new HashSet<>();
    static mapping={
        friends sqlType: 'VARBINARY(10000)'
    }

}
```

Now I've changed the field `friends` to a `HashMap<String,Integer>`. Now although I still map the field to varchar, Grails throws an exception every time I save an User object:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I first suspected that Grails keeps the old converting rule transforming HashSet to varbinary and it wasn't updated. So I tried changing the mapping from varbinary to blob and text, but neither worked.

I'm wondering if there are ways that I keep this column in varbinary in DB while letting Grails know that the attribute is now in HashMap and it should generate new ruls to convert.

Appreciate your insightful advice!

Edit: Im using Grails 2.4.4

Comment: have a look at the database migration plugin. It will take care for schema changes. https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration

Comment: @Sascha Seems pretty helpful :P I'll have a try on it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is one way I know of doing this: log into the database server so you have access to the database in a term window.  Do this first on your development machine.  Look at the relevant columns and see exactly which data types they use.  Then, on your development machine, drop those columns and deploy the changed project.  The new columns will be created if you've got the gorm set to 'update.' Again inspect the relevant columns and see if there's any way of changing the old columns (alter table...) in your production database to the new columns.  You'll have to stop your production server, make the changes, deploy the new project and restart it. If you can't just change the columns you may have to create the new ones, move data over and delete the old ones - all with the application server stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll try this evening :P. Actually I was thinking of doing similar modification on DB directly. I asked because I thought there might be a way that is more cohesive within Grails itself.